# "jQuery for React AST"?

Tags: babeljs, abstract-syntax-tree, acorn

Is there such a thing as a "jQuery for React AST"?  That like jQuery allows for elegant search, traversal, creation, mutation of an AST that contains things like JSXNode, etc?  I saw that acorn has some basic traversal stuff, but it isn't super usable for repeatedly doing reorders, insertions, wrapping a component in {flag && } to conditionally render, etc, etc.  I'm not even sure how to google for this except "jquery for AST" which, uh yeah, didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

## Subsecond

You can use [Subsecond](https://github.com/Subsecond-LLC/Subsecond) for this purpose, here is how it will looks like:

Input:

```js
<h1>hello world</h1>
```

Output:

```js
<h2>hello world</h2>
```

Transformation:

```js
S('JSXIdentifier').each((node) => {
  node.text('h2');
})
```

Here is [playground](https://playground.subsecond.app/).

## Putout

Also there is a way to do similar things using declarative approach with help of [Putout](https://github.com/coderaiser/putout) I'm working on:

### Change tag

**Input:**

```js
<h1>hello world</h1>
```

**Output:**

```js
<h2>hello world</h2>
```

**Transformation:**

```js
export const replace = () => ({
    '<h1>__a</h1>': '<h2>__a</h2>',
});
```

Here is [playground](https://putout.cloudcmd.io/#/gist/42107dbcd0dcca5c60e7237655136916/57102075cac4d06ac0c5ca8afb6e1c8d4f9b3c1e).

#### Change Attribute

You can also change an attribute `className` to `class`:

**Input:**

```js
const div = <div className="abc">{x}</div>
```

**Output:**

```js
const div = <div class="abc">{x}</div>
```

**Transformation:**

```js
export const replace = () => ({
    '<div className="__a">__jsx_children</div>': '<div class="__a">__jsx_children</div>',
});
```

Here is [playground](https://putout.cloudcmd.io/#/gist/42107dbcd0dcca5c60e7237655136916/a780bef3d4373bda03aad30e6904b53a19382d63)